# react router changes links url but doesnt display the components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I am designing a side nav in react, and I want to display a related component on the left side section of the Sidenav when I click on its items. however, react router changes the urls but doesnt show the components in the section. Here's my code:

**Sidenav.js**

```
import{ BrowserRouter,Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import {routes} from './../../routes.js'
...

class Sidebar extends Component {

    state = {
      navActive : '0'
    }

  render () {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <NavPanel dark style={{ backgroundColor: '#2d2e2e', height: '100vh', float:'right'}} >
        <NavTitle style={{ fontFamily: 'IranSans', textAlign: 'Center' }}>
       لوگو اینجا قرار بگیرد
        </NavTitle>
        <NavSection>
          <NavSectionTitle />
          <NavSectionTitle />  

          <NavLink  key='1' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<FiMonitor style={linkStyles.Icon} />} className={this.state.navActive === '1' ? 'active' :' ' }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ navActive:'1' })} style={this.state.navActive !== '1' ? {fontFamily:'IranSans'} : {...linkStyles.base, borderStyle:'solid',
          borderWidth:'0px 5px 0px 0px',
          borderColor:'#50d48b'
          }
          } 
          >
          <Link style={{color:'lightblue'}} to='./../../Views/Contents/Dashboard.js'>داشبورد</Link>          
          </NavLink>  

          <NavLink  key='2' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<IoIosAdd style={linkStyles.AddIcon} />} className={this.state.navActive === '2' ? 'active' :' ' }
            onClick={() => this.setState({ navActive:'2' })} style={this.state.navActive !== '2' ? {fontFamily:'IranSans'} : {...linkStyles.base, borderStyle:'solid',
            borderWidth:'0px 5px 0px 0px',
            borderColor:'#50d48b'
            }
            } 
            >
            <Link style={{color:'lightblue'}} to='./../../Views/Forms/CreateJob.js'>اضافه کردن فرصت شغلی</Link>             
            </NavLink>
           ....

        </NavSection>
        {routes.map((route, index) => (
          <Route
            key={index}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            component={route.main}
          />
        ))}
      </NavPanel>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default Radium(Sidebar)
```

**routes.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export const routes = [
  {
    path: './../../Views/Contents/Dashboard.js',
    exact: true,
    main: () => <h2>y</h2>
  },
  {
    path: './../../Views/Contents/CreateJob.js',
    exact: true,
    main: () => <h2>s</h2>
  },
  {
    path: './../../Views/Contents/Job.js',
    exact: true,
    main: () => <h2>r</h2>
  },
......
]
export default routes
```

**HRPanel.js**

```
import SideBar from './../../Components/SideBar/SideBar'
import NavBar from './../Navigation Bar/NavBar.js'

class HRPanel extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div id='App'>
        <SideBar />
        <NavBar />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default HRPanel
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Login from './Components/Login/Login.js'
import HRPanel from './Components/HR Panel/HRPanel.js'
import CreateJob from './Views/Forms/CreateJob.js'
import BasicInfo from './Views/Contents/BasicInfo.js'
import Dashboard from './Views/Contents/Dashboard.js'
import Education from './Views/Contents/Education.js'
import Feedback from './Views/Contents/Feedback.js'
import Finance from './Views/Contents/Finance.js'
import Insurance from './Views/Contents/Insurance.js'
import Jobs from './Views/Contents/Jobs.js'
import Management from './Views/Contents/Management.js'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

function App () {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path='./Components/HR Panel/HRPanel.js' component={HRPanel} />
        <Route exact path='./Views/Forms/CreateJob.js' component={CreateJob} />
        <Route exact path='./Views/Contents/BasicInfo.js' component={BasicInfo} />
        <Route exact path='./Views/Contents/Dashboard.js' component={Dashboard} />
        <Route exact path='./Views/Contents/Education.js' component={Education} />
        <Route exact path='./Views/Contents/Feedback.js' component={Feedback} />
        <Route exact path='./Views/Contents/Finance.js' component={Finance} />
        <Route exact path='./Views/Contents/Insurance.js' component={Insurance} />
        <Route exact path='./Views/Contents/Jobs.js' component={Jobs} />
        <Route exact path='./Views/Contents/Management.js' component={Management} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    // <Login> </Login>
    // <HRPanel> </HRPanel>
  )
}
export default App
```

what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying [path](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string) prop for `Route` component incorrectly. `path` is not a relative file path to a React component file, it's URL path to match. Change `path` in all spots of your components/files to be the URL path to match, rather than a path to a component. For example if you want `HRPanel` to display when the user navigates to `/hr`/ change the `path` for the `Route` to `<Route exact path='/hr' component={HRPanel} />`. `App.js` could look something like:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
    <Route exact path='/hr' component={HRPanel} />
    <Route exact path='/jobs/create' component={CreateJob} /> />
// ... remaining paths
  </Switch>
```

Also `Link` has prop [to](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-function) incorrect in the same way. `to` should specify the URL path to navigate to, not the relative path to the component. It should look like:

```
<Link style={{color:'lightblue'}} to='/dashboard'>داشبورد</Link>
```

Hopefully that helps

Comment: Sorry, so I have to randomly assign a url to them? for example in that dashboard line, how would it know where to go? Should I import the component first and then use it like Component={Dashboard} in the Navlink and then to='/dashboard'?

Comment: I wouldn't say "random". You would choose URL paths that represent navigation for youir application. What URL do you want to represent the view for `HRPanel`? What URL do you want to represent for `CreateJob`? For example, if this was a blog, probably you would have path `/posts` and `/posts/:id`. It's entirely depends on what you want navigation to look like.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer and sorry to ask a question again, but could you please look at this new issue too? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61139486/11675642