# React router sidebar routes correctly but doesn't show the component under the top menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I have designed a management panel in React with a sidebar and a top menu. when you click on any links on the sidebar, a component needs to be shown under the top menu. But even though the router links work correctly (they change the URL and they show the single component when I load the router link separately), they don't show anything under the top menu and next to the sidebar when I click on the sidebar links.
what seems to be the problem?

Edit: the github link of the project, its actually a very light project:
https://github.com/LaMentaAzul/Test

**Sidebar.js**

```
import{ BrowserRouter,Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import {routes} from './../../routes.js'
import CreateJob from './../../Views/Forms/CreateJob.js'
import BasicInfo from './../../Views/Contents/BasicInfo.js'
import Dashboard from './../../Views/Contents/Dashboard.js'
....

class Sidebar extends Component {

    state = {
      navActive : '0'
    }

  render () {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <ContainerVertical style={{ backgroundColor: '#2d2e2e', height: '100vh', float:'right'}} >
      <ContainerHorizontal >
      <NavPanel dark >
        <NavTitle style={{ fontFamily: 'IranSans', textAlign: 'Center' }}>
       لوگو اینجا قرار بگیرد
        </NavTitle>
        <NavSection>
          <NavSectionTitle />
          <NavSectionTitle />  

          <NavLink  key='1' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<FiMonitor style={linkStyles.Icon} />} className={this.state.navActive === '1' ? 'active' :' ' }
          onClick={() => this.setState({ navActive:'1' })} style={this.state.navActive !== '1' ? {fontFamily:'IranSans'} : {...linkStyles.base, borderStyle:'solid',
          borderWidth:'0px 5px 0px 0px',
          borderColor:'#50d48b'
          }
          } 
          >
          <Link Component={Dashboard} style={{color:'lightblue'}} to='/dashboard'>داشبورد</Link>          
          </NavLink>  

            ........

        {routes.map((route, index) => (
          <Route
            key={index}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            component={route.main}
          />
        ))}

      </NavPanel>
      </ContainerHorizontal>
      </ContainerVertical>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default Sidebar
```

**routes.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    exact: true
  },
  {
    path: '/createjob',
    exact: true
  }
....
]

export default routes
```

**HRPanel.js**

```
import SideBar from './../../Components/SideBar/SideBar'
import NavBar from './../Navigation Bar/NavBar.js'

class HRPanel extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div id='App'>
        <SideBar />
        <NavBar />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default HRPanel
```

**Dashboard.js(an example component of one of the links in the sidebar that needs to be loaded under the topbar)**

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <ContainerVertical>
        <ContainerHorizontal>
          <ScrollArea>
            <WidgetContainer style={{
              background: 'var(--bg-base)',
              border: '1px solid var(--border-color-base)',
              height: '400px',
              width: '100px',
              position: 'relative',
              top: '500px'
            }}
            >
              <Widget padding>
                <h2>
                   Title
                </h2>
              </Widget>
            </WidgetContainer>
          </ScrollArea>
        </ContainerHorizontal>
      </ContainerVertical>
    )
  }
}

export default Dashboard
```

**App.js**

```
.....

import Insurance from './Views/Contents/Insurance.js'
import Jobs from './Views/Contents/Jobs.js'
import Management from './Views/Contents/Management.js'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

function App () {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path='/hrpanel' component={HRPanel} />
        <Route exact path='/createjob' component={CreateJob} />
        <Route exact path='/basicinfo' component={BasicInfo} />
        <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
        <Route exact path='/education' component={Education} />
        <Route exact path='/feedback' component={Feedback} />
        <Route exact path='/finance' component={Finance} />
        <Route exact path='/insurance' component={Insurance} />
        <Route exact path='/jobs' component={Jobs} />
        <Route exact path='/management' component={Management} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    // <Login> </Login>
    // <HRPanel> </HRPanel>
  )
}
export default App
```

what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Your code is very long. Please provide a minimal example, so it's easier to assist you

Comment: Or try to get a codesandbox

Comment: create a simplied version of your issue on codesandbox etc. so we can see what's actually happening

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz
unfortunately I wasnt able to set up a asndbox. Id be more than greatful if you guys pulled the project from github because Im approaching a deadline: https://github.com/LaMentaAzul/Test/tree/master/front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is updated `Sidebar.js`

```
   import{ BrowserRouter,Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
    import {routes} from './../../routes.js'
    import CreateJob from './../../Views/Forms/CreateJob.js'
    import BasicInfo from './../../Views/Contents/BasicInfo.js'
    import Dashboard from './../../Views/Contents/Dashboard.js'

        class Sidebar extends Component {

            state = {
              navActive : '0'
            }

          render () {
            return (
              <BrowserRouter>
              <ContainerVertical style={{ backgroundColor: '#2d2e2e', height: '100vh', float:'right'}} >
              <ContainerHorizontal >
              <NavPanel dark >
                <NavTitle style={{ fontFamily: 'IranSans', textAlign: 'Center' }}>
               لوگو اینجا قرار بگیرد
                </NavTitle>
                <NavSection>
                  <NavSectionTitle />
                  <NavSectionTitle />  

                  <NavLink  key='1' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<FiMonitor style={linkStyles.Icon} />} className={this.state.navActive === '1' ? 'active' :' ' }
                  onClick={() => this.setState({ navActive:'1' })} style={this.state.navActive !== '1' ? {fontFamily:'IranSans'} : {...linkStyles.base, borderStyle:'solid',
                  borderWidth:'0px 5px 0px 0px',
                  borderColor:'#50d48b'
                  }
                  }
href="/dashboard" 
                  >
                 داشبورد       
                  </NavLink>  

                    ........

                {routes.map((route, index) => (
                  <Route
                    key={index}
                    path={route.path}
                    exact={route.exact}
                    component={route.main}
                  />
                ))}

              </NavPanel>
              </ContainerHorizontal>
              </ContainerVertical>
              </BrowserRouter>
            )
          }
        }

        export default Sidebar
```

NavLink and Link are both anchor tags so it shouldnt be nested.

And, you should use the same router in App.js and Sidebar.js

For example, your project now has got different routes

`<Route exact path='/jobs' component={Jobs} />` - App.js

`<Link Component={Jobs} style={{color:'lightblue'}} to='/ُjobs'>مشاهده فرصتهای شغلی</Link>` - Sidebar.js